# Authenticating against a Database. Hashing a password

Tags: symfony

How do I hash a password to store it in DB if bcrypt is used as algorithm?

```
security:
    encoders:
        Hoax\PartnerBundle\Entity\Partner:
            algorithm: bcrypt
```

I tried this code, but it returns different results all the time:

```
$factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
$user = new Hoax\PartnerBundle\Entity\Partner();

$encoder = $factory->getEncoder($user);
$password = $encoder->encodePassword('ryanpass', $user->getSalt());
$user->setPassword($password);
```

Comment: Is the salt different each time you try?  Your password will be a hash of the salt and your hashed password to prevent dictionary attacks and rainbow table attacks.

Comment: I think it is defined by bcrypt as Partner::getSalt() returns null. How do I encrypt it to store in the DB? I tried online tool and password is also different each time: https://www.dailycred.com/blog/12/bcrypt-calculator

Answer (score 0):

I am not too familiar with `bcrypt`, but the symfony docs give you the answer to your question.  And although it is best practice in most cases to use the Symfony2 salt method, it looks like bcrypt incorporates the salt into the password.  Read the [bcrypt](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#using-the-bcrypt-password-encoder) section of the symfony docs.

> A salt for each new password is generated automatically and need not be persisted. Since an encoded password contains the salt used to encode it, persisting the encoded password alone is enough.

This is why the password is different each time.  The hash itself already has the salt stored in there.  So the password 'password' will have a different hash each time it is 'bcrypt'ed because it includes the salt

Comment: If no salt is passed then you do indeed get a different encrypted password on each call which makes it impossible to check the password later on.  Which I am assuming is what @Roman wants to do.  Hence the need for the user object to generate and store a salt.

Comment: the salt is stored within the hash, check the link from @Roman Newaza, [dailycred.com/blog/12/bcrypt-calculator](http://dailycred.com/blog/12/bcrypt-calculator), even if there is a different hash, you can check the same password

Comment: By golly you are right.  The php function password_verify does not need a salt.  Learned something new.  So I wonder what the problem is?

Comment: I'm still confused how to make it working. I've noticed if I use constant salt, `$encoder->encodePassword()` returns the same result. How do I hash password to store it in the DB? Do I use this `$encoder->encodePassword()` method with some salt which is also stored in the DB? If it is like that why it is not mentioned in Symfony docs (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html)?

Comment: I have hrdcoded a salt to the Entity, updated password value in the DB with encoded password using the same salt and it works. Looks like Symfony2 doc is not so good